# Difference between references and foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

here are two declaration in sql

```
create table bookAdoption
(   
    courseId int,
    sem int,
    isbn int,
    PRIMARY KEY(courseId, sem, isbn),       
    FOREIGN KEY(courseId) REFERENCES course(courseId),
    FOREIGN KEY(sem) REFERENCES enroll(sem)
);
```

and the other one

```
CREATE TABLE bookAdoption
(
    courseId INT REFERENCES course(courseId) ,
    sem INT REFERENCES enroll(sem),
    isbn INT REFERENCES text1(isbn),
    PRIMARY KEY(courseId, sem, isbn)

);
```

what is the between using only references keyword

and using both references and foreign keyword both together
[image: screenshot]

Comment: According to the [grammar](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), only using references keyword like that is invalid syntax

Comment: @Esailija 
both works in mysql

Comment: @tiger When I run the second example verbatim, I get the expected syntax error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTREFERENCES course(courseId) , sem INT REFERENCES enroll(sem), isbn ' at line 3`

Comment: @Esailija spelling mistake it should be references instead of intreferences now try

Comment: @tiger still getting syntax error :) it never was `intreference`, but that's just a mistake in the report.

Comment: @ok i will post a screenshot

Comment: The second syntax is silently ignored by MySQL. It will **not** create a foreign key constraint.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's not silently ignored for me, using 5.5.15. Edit: Ok that was because of the trailing comma, it runs but does nothing now.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no I mean I got syntax error .. but that was because of the trailing comma in the original post.. it now gets silently ignored like you said

Comment: @Esailija: it ***is*** ignored (which is documented in the manual) No foreign key constraint will be created and you will be able to insert values that don't exist in the referenced table. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/725388/2

Comment: Foreign key is a reference key from any other table which links to the other table's UNIQUE key

Comment: @adeeliqbal Yes, but both ways are valid (ANSI/ISO SQL) syntax to declare such a constraint. The second way however, is parsed (as correct syntax) but ignored in MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the `REFERENCES` without a foreign key constraint, as quoted from the [MySQL Documentation, FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> Furthermore, InnoDB does not recognize or support “inline REFERENCES
>   specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references
>   are defined as part of the column specification. InnoDB accepts
>   REFERENCES clauses only when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN
>   KEY specification. For other storage engines, MySQL Server parses and
>   ignores foreign key specifications.

Answer (score 1):

A FOREIGN KEY can only reference a column that is UNIQUE.

In practice we ussualy add foreign key constraints to primary keys, and we say that the FK **references** the PK. But it is possible to add such a constraint with any UNIQUE column(s).

In order for this to work SQL syntax requires you to:

- declare a foreign key
- tell it what to reference

Answer (score -1):

```
What's the difference between foreign key constraint and referencing a column?
```

The difference is simple - column referencing is parsed but ignored.

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kIFbYwbj) - when column referencing is used then neither index nor constraint / foreign key are created.